# log cloud foundry syslog to s3 using the syslog protocol

Tags: amazon-s3, syslog, cloud-foundry

I want to send my syslog entries to an S3 bucket.  Security restrictions have meant that this is the only ways that I can do this.

With cloud foundry, you can create a user provided server where I specify a syslog url:

`cf create-user-provided-service DRAIN-NAME -l SYSLOG-URL`

Can I configure an s3 bucket to receive syslog messages using the syslog protocol?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Considering it as well?

Comment: I ended up using fluentd as described here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/fluentd.html.  Only I ended up putting fluentd onto a docker and putting the docker in a cf instance.  Was horribly complicated and a few months in a different contract